# Annotations in WPF window which has WindowsForms Panel thru. WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, annotations, wpf-controls

My WPF window has WindowsFormshost which in turn has a WindowsForms Panel. The Panel has live preview from camera. I want to draw annotations(draw some rectngles, lines etc..) 
on the image in the Panel. Is this possible in WPF with WindowsFormshost?

Any ideas?

Comment: no. crapforms is always on top (in z-order) of WPF due to it's limitations.